# is content within an element its child node?

Tags: html, dom

[image]

When watching the tutorial the teacher said that html was a child node of DOCUMENT, but said the text "jQuery Adventures" was "under" the title node.

So is the text within an element is technically a child node of that element or does it just appear under it in the DOM? Does it ever matter when coding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a contiguous run of text inside an element becomes a text node which is a child of that element.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(el.childNodes.length); // 1 child node
console.log(el.childNodes[0].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE); // text node
console.log(el.childNodes[0].nodeValue); // text contents
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes the text are child nodes of the elements that includes them and yes the structure of the DOM (parent and child structure) matters when you try to implement the UI and css styling of the webpages.